# Xcode 6 - iOS8 Constraints for Universal Apps

Tags: constraints, ios8, xcode6

Anyone know how to configure constraints or whatever, to achieve the correct implementation of a view object for all iPhones sizes?

Let me explain with an example:

In Xcode 6 (iOS 8) you do not have storyboard for iPad and storyboard for iPhone, but you want to implement a UIWebView for iPad and iPhones (3.5, 4, 4.7 and 5.5)

If you want to fill the entire screen with the UIWebView (it is only an example), what do you must do?

I have tried with parameters as "Scale to Fill" in the "Interface Builder", I have tried with:

```
    [self.webView setBounds:self.view.bounds];
```

You need to specify every size programmatically with "setFrame" ? I do not think so.

Some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. This is approximately, what I was looking for.

It is a tutorial from Skip Wilson. The link:

[iOS8 Constraints and Size Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem but I am not happy because I do not understand "Interface Builder Constraints" yet. I am not quiet.

My solution:

```
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**But I would like to know the way to build an "Object View" (UIWebview in example) that fits all screen sizes, and do it through the constraints tool.**

Considering the new situation (xCode 6): an unique storyboard for iPad and iPhone.